# Querying in the controller- ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**I am creating an application in Ruby and I have two model classes**

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :cuisine, :price_range, :environment
    self.primary_key = 'title'
     has_many :environments
    end
end


class Environment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :type
     belongs_to :restaurants,foreign_key: 'title'

end
```

**I am trying to query two tables in the controller- to return restaurants with specific environments.**

```
@restaurants = Restaurant.joins('INNER JOIN environments ON restaurants.title=environments.title').where('environments.env_type'=> @selected_environment)
```

NOTE: @selected_environment is a hash contained list of environments. Environments table has a list of environment and restaurant pairs(there can be more than one restaurant).
I know the query above is not correct to achieve my goal. Is there a way i can get this done?

controller method:

```
  def index

         # can later be moved to the Restaurant model
         ordering = {:title => :asc}
         @all_environments = Restaurant.all_environments

         @selected_environments = params[:environments] || session[:environments] || {}
         if @selected_environments == {}
           @selected_environments = Hash[@all_environments.map {|environment| [environment, environment]}]
         end
         if params[:environments] != session[:environments]
           session[:environments] = @selected_environments
           redirect_to :environments => @selected_environments and return
         end
        @restaurants = Restaurant.joins(:environments).where(environments:{env_type: @selected_environments.keys })

  end
```

Comment: I think you've modelled your data incorrectly, and that could be the source of some of your problems. Can you give some examples of data? (eg, restaurants, environments, and the relationship between them?)

Also, is there any specific reason why you've chosen 'title' as your primary key over the idiomatic 'id'?

Comment: Yeah, I did answer this, but reading through this are you trying to do a query after someone selects a selected_environment on the ui?

Comment: yes DustinFisher that is correct

Comment: What controller are you doing this from? What's the full method on the controller?

Answer (score 1):

For your models you want to do this:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :cuisine, :price_range, :environment
  self.primary_key = 'title'
  has_many :environments, :foreign_key => 'title', :primary_key => 'title'
end


class Environment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :type
  belongs_to :restaurants, foreign_key: 'title'
end
```

Try structuring your query like this:

```
Restaurant.joins(:environments).where(environments: { env_type: @selected_environments.values })
```

Comment: I am getting the following SQL lite error 
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: environments.restaurant_id: SELECT "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants" INNER JOIN "environments" ON "environments"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."title" WHERE "environments"."env_type" IN ('casual', 'outdoor_sitting', 'romantic')

Comment: the join is picking up a non existent restaurant_id instead of the title

Comment: I updated the answer for your structure on your models.

Comment: This is still not working- It works fine without the where clause.I have updated my controller method above.